# uint16 image to float - histogram stretching?

Tags: image-processing

I have an uint16 satellite image whose values range from 0 to 3458 and its histogram is like this:

[original histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mutup.png)

I want to convert the image to float (range 0-1) but of course, I can simply divide everything by 3458 otherwise I will get a very dark image (because most pixels are below 500 as you can see from the histogram).

I would like to get a histogram like this:
[new histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAp3Y.png)
but I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: So divide by 500, or by 1000, or whatever you need to get a good view of your data. I'm not sure what you're looking for. Are you interested in a non-linear mapping maybe?

Comment: Basically, if I have a pixel distribution within the interval (0;3458), I would like to have the same pixel distribution mapped into (0;1)

Comment: Yes, dividing by 3458 will do that, but you don’t want that solution. So my question is: do you want to clip higher values off, or do you want a more complex non-linear mapping that distorts the data more?

Comment: Hi Cris, yes what I have done so far is simply implementing a cut-off clipping: basically every pixel is divided by such cut value, and pixels larger than 1 are mapped into 1. But I guess there are nicer solutions.

Comment: There are a million and one mappings you might apply, for example a logarithmic mapping or an error function or a sigmoid function, or ... It depends on what your data *means*, which of these are applicable and meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should convert your image type to float precision. If you are using MATLAB the function that can help you could be *im2double()*.
Secondly, are you using *imhist()* function to show your histogram? If yes, It can easily get the range of bins you want to show your histogram.

Comment: I am using Python